# Select maximum value of one table depending on 2 other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have 3 tables

```
Orders (orderID, CustomerID)
Orderlines (orderID, ProdID) 
Products (ProdID, CategoryID)!
```

I want to find the customerID which has the most different "CategoryID" in one order!

Comment: Can you provide sample SQL that you tried to this moment?

Comment: Could toy post an example please?

Comment: i havent thought of something to try thats why I am asking! i dont know how to start!

Comment: Your first task should be to write a statement that returns all the necessary information prior to you finding out who has the most distinct categoryids.

Comment: google for joins, count, distinct ... start from there

Comment: ok! thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 2):

To get you there, start with the basic query to get your info:

```
SELECT o.customer_id
      ,l.orderid
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) category_cnt
FROM orders o 
 JOIN  orderlines l on l.orderid = o.orderid
 JOIN products p ON l.prodid = p.prodid
GROUP BY l.customner_id, l.orderid
order by COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) desc;
```

Once you see that this works out, we will add an analytic to this to show you the rank() function

```
SELECT o.customer_id
      ,l.orderid
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) category_cnt
      , rank() over (order by COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) desc) as count_rank
FROM  orders o 
 JOIN orderlines l  on l.orderid = o.orderid
 JOIN products p ON l.prodid = p.prodid
GROUP BY l.customner_id, l.orderid
order by COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) desc;
```

Following so far? OK, so now we just need to push this down into a sub-query to get the record(s) ranked #1 (in case more than one customer order matches the top count)

```
SELECT customer_id, order_id, category_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT o.customer_id
          ,l.orderid
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) category_cnt
          , rank() over (order by COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) desc) as count_rank
    FROM  orders o 
     JOIN orderlines l  on l.orderid = o.orderid
     JOIN products p ON l.prodid = p.prodid
    GROUP BY l.customner_id, l.orderid)
WHERE count_rank = 1;
```

Comment: Good explanation and a nice compact query. You are missing the `by` in `rank() over (order by COUNT`.

Comment: Fixed - thanks for noticing that. Always fun writing code without means to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
with data_a as (    --distinct  CategoryID cnt
    select 
        o.orderID,
        o.customerID,
        count(DISTINCT p.CategoryID) cnt
    from Orders o
    join Orderlines ol.orderID = o.orderID
    join Products p on  p.ProdID  = ol.ProdID
    group by o.orderID, o.customerID
),
data as (    --get all count rnk
    select
        orderID,
        customerID,
        rank() over (partition by orderID, customerID order by cnt desc)  rnk
    from data_a
)
select
    orderID,
    customerID
from  data
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step: Count distinct categories per order first. Then rank your orders, so that the orders with the most categories get rank #1. Then find customers for all orders ranked #1.

```
select distinct cutomerid
from orders
where orderid in
(
  select orderid
  from
  (
    select orderid, rank() over (order by category_count desc) as rnk
    from
    (
      select ol.orderid, count(distinct p.distinctcategroyid) as category_count
      from orderlines ol
      join products p on p.prodid = ol.prodid
      group by ol.orderid
    ) counted
  ) ranked
  where rnk = 1
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like that i guess

```
SELECT o.customerID, t.category_cnt 
  FROM (SELECT l.orderid, COUNT(DISTINCT categoryid) category_cnt
          FROM orderlines l
          JOIN products p ON l.prodid = p.prodid
          GROUP BY l.orderid
         ORDER BY category_cnt DESC) t
  JOIN orders o ON o.orderid = t.orderid
 WHERE rownum < 2
```